# Filing Structure / C

Tags: c, file, struct

I am getting error after fill information.I dont know where did i make mistake.I want to get information via structure and then save in biodata.txt file.This is just for starting for my program then i will add "delete edit search" options.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct biodata{
       int recno,age;
       char name[20],sex;
       float salary;
}obj;

int main(){
    int addData();
    int showRecord();
    char choice;

    while(1){
        printf("\n\n*****CHOOSE YOUR CHOICE*****\n");
        printf("1) ADD DATA\n");
        printf("2) SHOW RECORD\n");
        printf("Enter your choice : ");

        choice = getche();
        switch(choice){
            case '1' :  
                addData();
                break;
        }
    }
}

int addData(){
     FILE *fp;
     fp = fopen("biodata.txt","w+");

     printf("\n*****ADDING DATA*****\n");
     printf("\nEnter Record No : ");
     scanf("%d",&obj.recno);
     printf("Enter Name : ");

     scanf("%s",obj.name);
     printf("Enter age : ");
     scanf("%d",&obj.age);

     printf("Enter Sex : ");
     scanf("%s",obj.sex);

     printf("Enter Salary : ");
     scanf("%f",&obj.salary);
     fwrite(&obj,sizeof(obj),1,fp);

     fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Can you please quote the exact error you're getting?

Comment: "Choose your choice" seems rather tautological.

Comment: Side note: you will benefit greatly from a well-indented code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing:

```
printf("Enter Sex : ");
scanf("%s",obj.sex);
```

But obj.sex is of char type:

```
struct biodata{
        int recno,age;
        char name[20],sex;
        float salary;
}obj;
```

Change the scanf to:

```
scanf("%c",&obj.sex);
```

Comment: Of course, watch out for http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfc.html ... and better to just avoid `scanf` entirely. http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: thanks now i did like that but in biodata.txt it written 
     Jack                Male      HC
but it must be 
1 Jack 22 Male 200

last form of algorithm
https://www.dropbox.com/s/k0ay3m7kg9lyl70/dosyam.txt

Comment: @allstar: Then you need to deal with it in the same way that you handle the `name` field: the `sex` member needs to be either a `char` array or a `char*` (with memory allocated for it). (Incidentally, the way you're currently reading `name` is asking for a buffer overflow.)